# How to write data to a Postgres OID column with Hibernate?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have a table in which there is an OID column for storing large objects, like this:

```
public class MyTable...{
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "image")
    private byte[] image;
    ...
}
```

I'm tring to write the bytes to the image array and then persist the object, but this does not seem to be working. The object is not persisted to the database, so I assume the transaction is being rolledback somewhere during the process.

Is it possible to write Large Objects like this? Or do I need to save the bytes as a file somewhere in the filesystem and then use the lo_import() function?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace or error message?

Comment: @mm759 It doesn't generate any error messages. I can see the insert being performed in the hibernate logs, but the row is not being actually inserted in the database.

Comment: Doe you see the rollback in the locks that you believe in?